# Copying local files with curl

Tags: linux, unix, curl

Is there a way to copy local files with curl, I need it to work as an alternative for cp command.

This is a bit strange, but I'm working on an environment where cp is not available.

Comment: Pretty sure you don't care at all 2 years after, but I would have avoided `curl` and used `cat` + basic shell redirection : `cat sourceFile > targetFile`

Comment: @Aaron for me , it's better to use curl as i would be able to use same code for remote and local downloads without overcomplicating it with if statements

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could say:

```
curl -o /path/to/destination file:///path/to/source/file
```

This would copy `/path/to/source/file` to `/path/to/destination`.

Comment: or ```curl file:///path/to/source/file > /path/to/destination``` which uses plain shell redirection.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `rsync`

```
rsync -avz /path/to/src/file /path/to/dst/dir
```

You can also use tar

```
cd /path/to/src/dir; tar -cpf - sourcefile | (cd /path/to/dest/dir; tar -xpf -)
```

if your tar support `-C`

```
cd /path/to/src/dir; tar -cpf - sourcefile | tar -xpf - -C /path/to/dest/dir
```