# Copy file on Synology using the Task Scheduler

Tags: curl, synology

I'm trying to copy a small text file from/to locations which are located under different subfolders of the "web" main folder.

The source is 'web/Domoos/php_scripts/auto/file/myfox_token.txt' and the destination is 'web/Demo/0h/php_scripts/auto/file/myfox_token.txt'.

Based on a previous post on stackoverflow ([Copying local files with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023048/copying-local-files-with-curl)), I have tried to implement this logic in my Synology DS415+, which runs under DSM version 6.2.3 (Update 2) by adding a new task and entering the following in the command line:

```
curl -o file://"web/Domoos/php_scripts/auto/file/myfox_token.txt" > "web/Demo/0h/php_scripts/auto/file/myfox_token.txt"
```

Unfortunately, I was not successful. Then I tried to enter the same using the IP address of my NAS (192.168.X.X) :

```
curl -o "192.168.X.X/web/Domoos/php_scripts/auto/file/myfox_token.txt" > "192.168.X.X/web/Demo/0h/php_scripts/auto/file/myfox_token.txt"
```

This was not successful, either.

Could it be that the "curl" function is not supported on Synology as I would like it to be ?

Many thanks for reading my post and best wishes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I respond to myself, hoping that this post could be helpful to someone else.

I created a bash script and went in the 3rd tab of the task scheduler editor "task settings".

I entered the following

```
#!/bin/bash
# For demo 0h folder
sleep 15s
cp /volume1/web/Domoos/php_scripts/auto/file/myfox_token_extracted.txt /volume1/web/Demo/0h/php_scripts/auto/file/myfox_token_extracted.txt
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Please keep in mind that :

1. #!/bin/bash is a so-called 'Shebang' which will instruct your Synology OS to parse the rest of the command line(s) as an interpreter directive.
2. The second line is just a comment example and starts with the hash character (#).

Best wishes and stay healthy

Comment: Thanks for sharing! It looks great! Would you like to share why we need sleep 15 second before copy the files?

Comment: @JeromeLi : thank you and hope this could somehow be helpful for you. Actually I'm waiting 15 seconds because I have 2 scripts which run in parallel (each 1/2 hour). Let's say that this very script is number 2. Script number 1 regenerates the token every half-hour. As I was not sure how the Synology prioritise 2 scripts running at the same time, I wanted to ensure that the copy is done on a "fresh" copy of the newly generated token. Hope this helps.